# how to convert this SQL query to eloquent in Laravel

Tags: php, sql, laravel, eloquent, laravel-7

I am trying to convert this SQL query to Eloquent in Laravel

Convert SQL code to Eloquent

```sql
SELECT
  session_id,
  SUM(points) AS total_points 
FROM
  (
    SELECT
      session_id,
      spent_points AS points 
    FROM
      session_details 
    WHERE
      session_id IN 
      (
        " - Meagevy6y9ukbmFXvB7",
        " - Meak6dG9iqvHWfAGQvy"
      )
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
      session_id,
      price_points 
    FROM
      template_sales 
    WHERE
      session_id IN 
      (
        " - Meagevy6y9ukbmFXvB7",
        " - Meak6dG9iqvHWfAGQvy"
      )
  )
  t 
GROUP BY
  session_id
```

my code in Laravel but not working

```
$ids = ["-Meagevy6y9ukbmFXvB7","-Meak6dG9iqvHWfAGQvy"];
$query = DB::table('session_details')
    ->select('session_id',DB::raw('SUM(points) AS total_points FROM ( SELECT session_id, spent_points AS points FROM session_details
    WHERE session_id IN ("'.$ids.'") UNION ALL SELECT session_id,price_points FROM template_sales WHERE session_id IN ("'.$ids.'") ) t GROUP BY session_id'))
->get();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is documentation available for all the operations in your query.

- For selected columns use `select('column1', 'column2', ...)`
- For selected aggregate columns use `selectRaw('sum(column) as column')`
- For `WHERE column IN (...)` use `whereIn('column', $array)`
- For subquery tables, use `Closures` or `Builder` classes (`DB::table(fn($q) => ... , alias)` or `DB::table($builder, alias)`)
- For `UNION ALL` use `unionAll()` with the same syntax as subquery tables.

#### Option 1: Closures

```php
$ids = ["-Meagevy6y9ukbmFXvB7","-Meak6dG9iqvHWfAGQvy"];
$query = DB::table(function ($sub) use ($ids) {
        $sub->select('session_id', 'spent_points as points')
            ->from('session_details')
            ->whereIn('session_id', [1,2])
            ->unionAll(function ($union) use ($ids) {
                $union->select('session_id', 'price_points')
                      ->from('template_sales')
                      ->whereIn('session_id', $ids);
            });
    }), 't')
    ->select('session_id')
    ->selectRaw('sum(points) as total_points')
    ->groupBy('session_id')
    ->get();
```

#### Option 2: Builder (or translating the subqueries from the inside-out)

```php
$ids = ["-Meagevy6y9ukbmFXvB7","-Meak6dG9iqvHWfAGQvy"];

$union = DB::table('template_sales')
    ->select('session_id', 'price_points')
    ->whereIn('session_id', $ids);

$sub = DB::table('session_details')
    ->select('session_id', 'spent_points as points')
    ->whereIn('session_id', $ids)
    ->unionAll($union);

$query = DB::table($sub, 't')
    ->select('session_id')
    ->selectRaw('sum(points) as total_points')
    ->groupBy('session_id')
    ->get();
```

Pick whichever you prefer. Both evaluate to the same query you posted.

Answer (score 3):

I'd advise you to use Eloquent models & Eloquent relationships to make the query more readable.

Execute the following in your terminal to create a new model:

```
php artisan make:model SessionDetail
```

Open the file that Laravel has generated for you in /app/Models (or whatever folders your models are in), and set the table in the model by putting the following property into the model class: `public $table = "session_details";`

If your model does not use or have Laravel timestamps which are usually created_at & updated_at, you can also use this property to disable them in the model: `public $timestamps = false;`

After that, create generate another model by execute the following command in your terminal:

```
php artisan make:model TemplateSale
```

Follow the same instructions again but this time change the table name to `template_sales`

After you have done that, head into your SessionDetail model and make a relationship to the TemplateSale model using the following code (this must be in the model class beneath the properties):

```
public function template_sales() {
   return $this->hasMany(TemplateSale::class);
}
```

After that, you can replace your query with this line of code:

```
$query = \App\Models\SessionDetail::select("session_id", "SUM(points) as total_points")->whereIn("session_id", $ids)->get();
```

To get the template sales from that query, you have to use `$query->template_sales;`

If I got anything wrong, please tell me & I'll fix it ASAP

Comment: I prefer this answer, it is by far to invest in the longer game, write models, write relationships, write tests. You're investing in yourself and your team making future development and fixed easier.